# What simple techniques do you use to improve performance?

Tags: code-quality, performance

I'm talking about the way we write simple routines in order to improve performance without making your code harder to read... for instance, this is the typical for we learned:

```
for(int i = 0; i < collection.length(); i++ ){
   // stuff here
}
```

But, I usually do this when a `foreach` is not applicable:

```
for(int i = 0, j = collection.length(); i < j; i++ ){
   // stuff here
}
```

I think this is a better approach since it will call the `length` method once only... my girlfriend says it's cryptic though. Is there any other simple trick you use on your own developments?

Comment: `collection.length()` should in my opinion normally be an O(1) operation... (ie the class should normally update a private field called `length` or something)

Comment: Yup... but in machine language, `i < collection.length()` is like: `x = collection.length(); i < x` which will require more steps.

Comment: @mathepic, what if it was 'i < sqrt( coll.length() )' ?  Removing loop invariants _is_ a good technique.

Comment: +1 just for having a girlfriend who will tell you when your code isn't clear.

Comment: You're just posting this to tell us you have a girlfriend.

Comment: @Josh hahaha... well... maybe.

Comment: @Christian: Don't forget that there are compiler optimizations which might do this for you so you might only be affecting readability and not affecting performance at all; premature optimization is the root of all evil... Try to avoid more than one declaration or assignment on the same line, don't make people read it twice... You should use the normal way (your first example) or put the second declaration outside the for loop (although that also decreases readability as you would need to read back to see what the j means).

Comment: @TomWij: The correct (and complete) quote:  *"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."*

Comment: True, but that doesn't change anything... If you're spending the critical 3% to these small useless changes instead of some nifty high-level optimizations then there it is no opportunity at all.

Comment: @tomwij:  If you are spending the three percent, then by definition you should be doing it in time-critical code, and not wasting your time on the other 97%.

Comment: Why do you keep trying to correct me? While you don't fully understand the definition yourself? It's not 3% of the time-critical code, it's 3% of the time. I did say that one should be adjusting the time-critical code, as you look from a high-level view what code needs improvement rather than randomly applying small useless changes.

Comment: @TomWij: You're not the first person to misquote Knuth.  My point is that many programmers use the misquote as an excuse to forego early optimizations to their designs (that critical 3%), a tragic (and easily avoidable) mistake.

Comment: Ah, I see... Thank you for that quote, could be useful in that case.

Comment: FWIW, if this is multithreaded code, you have no guarantee that `collection.length()` will always return the same value, unless you lock it or otherwise synchronize access.

Comment: To improve readability on the second one, change j to a meaningful name like maxLength or something. It will maybe not be as readable as the first but you will have both performance and approach the first sample's readability. I normally use iterators so for(SomeIterator it = collection.begin(), endIt = collection.end(); it != endIt; it++){}

Comment: For loops over the indexes of a collection should be performed by muscle memory. Changing the way one is written is a waste of brain cycles on par with creating a new recipe for peanut butter and jelly sandwiches.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

*insert premature-discussion-is-the-root-of-all-evil lecture*

That said, here are some habits I've gotten into to avoid unnecessary efficiency, and in some cases, make my code simpler and more correct as well.

This isn't a discussion of general principles, but of some things to be aware of to avoid introducing unnecessary inefficiencies into code.

### Know your [big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions)

This should probably be merged into the lengthy discussion above.  It's pretty much common sense that a loop inside of a loop, where the inner loop repeats a calculation, is gonna be slower.  For example:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
    ...
}
```

This will take a horrendous amount of time if the string is really long, because the length is being recalculated on every iteration of the loop.  Note that [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) actually optimizes this case because `strlen()` is marked as a pure function.

When sorting a million 32-bit integers, [bubble sort would be the wrong way to go](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4RRi_ntQc8).  In general, sorting can be done in O(n * log n) time (or better, in the case of radix sort), so unless you know your data is going to be small, look for an algorithm that's at least O(n * log n).

Likewise, when dealing with databases, be aware of indexes.  If you `SELECT * FROM people WHERE age = 20`, and you don't have an index on people(age), it'll require an O(n) sequential scan rather than a much faster O(log n) index scan.

### Integer arithmetic hierarchy

When programming in C, bear in mind that some arithmetic operations are more expensive than others.  For integers, the hierarchy goes something like this (least expensive first):

- `+ - ~ & | ^`
- `<< >>`
- `*`
- `/`

Granted, the compiler will usually optimize things like `n / 2` to `n >> 1` automatically if you're targeting a mainstream computer, but if you're targeting an embedded device, you might not get that luxury.

Also, `% 2` and `& 1` have different semantics.  Division and modulus usually rounds toward zero, but it's implementation defined.  Good ol' `>>` and `&` always rounds toward negative infinity, which (in my opinion) makes a lot more sense.  For instance, on my computer:

```
printf("%d\n", -1 % 2); // -1 (maybe)
printf("%d\n", -1 & 1); // 1
```

Hence, use what makes sense.  Don't think you're being a good boy by using `% 2` when you were originally going to write `& 1`.

### Expensive floating point operations

Avoid heavy floating point operations like `pow()` and `log()` in code that doesn't really need them, especially when dealing with integers.  Take, for example, reading a number:

```
int parseInt(const char *str)
{
    const char *p;
    int         digits;
    int         number;
    int         position;

    // Count the number of digits
    for (p = str; isdigit(*p); p++)
        {}
    digits = p - str;

    // Sum the digits, multiplying them by their respective power of 10.
    number = 0;
    position = digits - 1;
    for (p = str; isdigit(*p); p++, position--)
        number += (*p - '0') * pow(10, position);

    return number;
}
```

Not only is this use of `pow()` (and the `int`<->`double` conversions needed to use it) rather expensive, but it creates an opportunity for precision loss (incidentally, the code above doesn't have precision issues).  That's why I wince when I see this type of function used in a non-mathematical context.

Also, notice how the "clever" algorithm below, which multiplies by 10 on each iteration, is actually more concise than the code above:

```
int parseInt(const char *str)
{
    const char *p;
    int         number;

    number = 0;
    for (p = str; isdigit(*p); p++) {
        number *= 10;
        number += *p - '0';
    }

    return number;
}
```

Comment: Very thorough answer.

Comment: Note, the premature optimization discussion does not apply for garbage code.  You should always use an implementation working well in the first place.

Comment: *Note that GCC actually optimizes this case because strlen() is marked as a pure function.*  I think you mean that it is a const function, not pure.

Comment: @Andy Lester: Actually, I did mean pure.  [In the GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bconst_007d-function-attribute-2403), it states that const is slightly stricter than pure in that a const function cannot read global memory.  `strlen()` examines the string pointed to by its pointer argument, meaning it can't be const.  Also, `strlen()` is indeed marked as pure in glibc's `string.h`

Comment: You're right, my mistake, and I should have double-checked.  I've been working on the Parrot project annotating functions as either `pure` or `const` and even documented it in the header file because of the subtle difference between the two. http://docs.parrot.org/parrot/1.3.0/html/docs/dev/c_functions.pod.html

Comment: +1 for sparing us the tedious root of all evil discussion...

Comment: But the compiler can only move the `strlen` call out of the loop if it can prove that the string is not modified inside the loop. If the loop body calls `foo(str)` and the compiler cannot see the definition of `foo`, it has no license to optimize.

Answer (score 13):

From your question and the comment thread, it sounds like you "think" that this code change improves performance, but you don't really know whether it does or not.

I'm a fan of [Kent Beck's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Beck) philosophy:

> "Make it work, make it right, make it fast."

My technique to improve code performance, is first get the code passing the unit tests and well factored and then (particularly for looping operations) write a unit test that checks performance and then refactor the code or think of a different algorithm if the one I've chosen isn't working as expected.

For example, to test speed with .NET code I use [NUnit's Timeout attribute](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=timeout&r=2.5) to write assertions that a call to a particular method will execute within a certain amount of time.

Using something like NUnit's timeout attribute with the code example you gave (and a large number of iterations for the loop), you could actually prove whether or not your "improvement" to the code really did help with the perfomance of that loop.

One disclaimer: While this is effective at the "micro" level, it is certainly not the only way to test performance and doesn't take into account issues that might arise at the "macro" level - but it's a good start.

Comment: While I am a big believer in profiling,  I also believe it is smart to keep the kinds of tips Cristian is looking for in mind.  I will always choose the faster of two equally readable methods.  Being forced into post-mature optimization is no fun.

Comment: There is not necessarily need for unit tests, but it is always worthwhile to spend this 20 minutes to check if some performance myth is true or not, especially because answer often depends on compiler and state of -O and -g flag (or Debug/Release in case of VS).

Comment: +1 This answer supplements my related comment to the question itself.

Comment: @AShelly: if we're talking about simple reformulations of loop syntax, changing it after the fact is very easy to do. Also, what you find equally readable might not be so for other programmers. Best to use "standard" syntax as much as possible, and only vary it when proven necessary.

Comment: @AShelly surely if you can think of two equally readable methods and you choose the less efficient one you're just not doing your job? Would anyone actually do that?

Comment: @glenatron, sure they do, see @Joeri's answer.  Many people code by rote patterns, without thinking of the efficiency of it.  And not everyone agrees on readable.

Answer (score 11):

Bear in mind that your compiler may well turn:

```
for(int i = 0; i < collection.length(); i++ ){
   // stuff here
}
```

into:

```
int j = collection.length();
for(int i = 0; i < j; i++ ){
   // stuff here
}
```

or something similar, if `collection` is unchanged over the loop.

If this code is in a time critical section of your application it would be worth finding out whether this is the case or not - or indeed whether you can change the compiler options to do this.

This will maintain the readability of the code (as the former is what most people will expect to see), while gaining you those few extra machine cycles. You are then free to concentrate on the other areas where the compiler can't help you.

On a side note: if you change `collection` inside the loop by adding or removing elements (yes, I know it's a bad idea, but it does happen) then your second example either won't loop over all the elements or will try to access past the end of the array.

Comment: Why not just do it explicitly?

Comment: In some languages that bounds-check, you will SLOW your code if you do it explicitly. With a loop to collection.length the compiler moves it out for you and omits the bounds check. With a loop to some constant from elsewhere in your app you'll have a bounds check on every iteration. That's why it's important to measure - intuition about performance is almost never right.

Comment: Which is why I said "it would be worth finding out".

Comment: How can the C# compiler know that collection.length() doesn't modify collection, in the way that stack.pop() does? I think it would be best to check the IL rather than assume the compiler optimises this. In C++, you can mark a method as const ('does not change the object'), so the compiler can make this optimisation safely.

Comment: @JBRW Optimizers that do this are also aware of the ok-let's-call-it-constness-even-though-this-isn't-C++ of methods of the collections. After all you can only bounds-check if you can notice that something is a collection and know how to get its length.

Answer (score 9):

This kind of optimization is usually not recommended. That piece of optimization can easily be done by compiler, you are working with a higher level programming language instead of assembly, so think in the same level.

Comment: Give her a book about programming ;)

Comment: +1, as most of our girlfriends are likely more interested in Lady Gaga than code clarity.

Comment: Could you explain why it's not recommended?

Comment: @macneil well... that trick makes codes not that common and totally doesn't work, that piece of optimization is supposed to be done by compiler.

Comment: @macneil if you are working in a higher level language, think in the same level.

Comment: I was suggesting that you edit your answer so it could be more helpful. Your answer is mostly a comment on commenting and not helpful, but it sounds like you have an idea in mind that could make it helpful.

Comment: @macneil :D fine, suggestion taken

Answer (score 4):

I have a very simple technique.

1. I make my code work.
2. I test it for speed.
3. If it's fast, I go back to step 1 for some other feature.  If it's slow, I profile it to find the bottleneck.
4. I fix the bottleneck.  Go back to step 1.

There are plenty of times where it saves time to circumvent this process, but in general you'll know if that's the case.  If there's doubt, I stick to this by default.

Answer (score 3):

This may not apply so much for general purpose coding, but I do mostly embedded development these days.  We have a specific target processor (which is not going to get faster - it will seem quaintly obsolete by the time they retire the system in 20+ years), and very restrictive timing deadlines for much of the code.  The processor, like all processors, has certain quirks regarding which operations are fast or slow.

We have a technique used to ensure we are generating the most efficient code, while maintaining readibility for the whole team.  In those places where the most natural language construct does not generate the most efficient code, we have created a macros that do ensure the optimal code is used.  If we do a follow-on project for a different processor, we can update the macros for the optimal method on that processor.

As a specific example, for our current processor, branches empty the pipeline, stalling the processor for 8 cycles.  The compiler takes this code:

```
 bool isReady = (value > TriggerLevel);
```

and turns it into the assembly equivalent of

```
isReady = 0
if (value > TriggerLevel)
{
  isReady = 1;
}
```

This will either take 3 cycles, or 10 if it jumps over `isReady=1;`.  But the processor has a single-cycle `max` instruction, so it is much better to write code to generate this sequence which is guaranteed to always take 3 cycles:

```
diff = value-TriggerLevel;
diff = max(diff, 0);
isReady = min(1,diff);
```

Obviously, the intent here is less clear than the original.   So we have created a macro, which we use whenever we want a boolean Greater-Than comparison:

```
#define BOOL_GT(a,b) min(max((a)-(b),0),1)

//isReady = value > TriggerLevel;
isReady = BOOL_GT(value, TriggerLevel);
```

We can do similar things for other comparisons.  To an outsider, the code is a bit less readable than if we only used the natural construct. However it quickly becomes clear after spending a little time working with the code, and it is much better than letting every programmer experiment with their own optimization techniques.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the first advice would be to avoid such premature optimisations until you know exactly what's happening to the code, so that you are sure that you are actually making it faster, and not slower.

In C# for example the compiler will optimise the code if you are looping the length of an array, as it knows that it doesn't have to range check the index when you access the array. If you try to optimise it by putting the array length in a variable, you will break the connection between the loop and the array, and actually make the code a lot slower.

If you are going to micro-optimise, you should limit yourself to things that are known to use a lot of resources. If there is just a slight performance gain, you should go with the most readable and maintainable code instead. How computer work change over time, so something that you find out is slightly faster now, may not stay that way.

Answer (score 2):

**Take advantage of short-circuiting:**

`if(someVar || SomeMethod())`

takes just as long to code, and is just as readable as:

`if(someMethod() || someVar)`

yet it's going to evaluate more quickly over time.

Answer (score 1):

Wait six months, get your boss to buy everyone new computers.  Seriously.  Programmer time is way more expensive than hardware in the long run.  High performance computers allow coders to write code in a straightforward manner without being as concerned about speed.

Comment: Er...What about the performance your customers see?  Are you wealthy enough to buy new computers for them also?

Comment: And we have almost hit the performance wall; multicore computation is the only way out, but waiting won't make your programs use it.

Comment: +1 This answer supplements my related comment to the question itself.

Comment: No programming time is not more expensive than hardware when you have thousands or milllion of users.  Programmer time is NOT more important than user time, get this through your head as soon as possible.

Comment: @Robert, @HLGEM, it depends on what kind of software you write.  Shrinkwrap is different from simulations is different from web-based, etc.  My point is that spending $50k to buy new rigs for a small group of developers is insignificant in the long run when viewed against their overall productivity.

Comment: Get into good habits, then it doesn't take any programmer time as it is what you do all the time.

Comment: Today's computers are fast. They handle most problems easily. The ones they don't handle rarely can be handled by a computer that is only twice as fast. On the other hand, in my experience most code that wasn't developed with care for performance can be made ten times faster with some effort.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to optimize too much ahead of time, then when you do optimize worry a bit less about readability.

There little I hate more than unnecessary complexity, but when you hit a complex situation a complex solution is often required.

If you write the code the most obvious way then make a comment explaining why it has been altered when you make the complex change.

Specifically to your meaning though, I find that a lot of times doing the Boolean opposite of the default approach sometimes helps:

```
for(int i = 0, j = collection.length(); i < j; i++ ){
// stuff here
}
```

can become

```
for(int i = collection.length(); i > 0; i-=1 ){
// stuff here
}
```

In many languages as long as you make appropriate adjustments to the "stuff" part and it is still readable.  It just doesn't approach the problem the way most people would think of doing it first because it counts backwards.

in c#for example:

```
        string[] collection = {"a","b"};

        string result = "";

        for (int i = 0, j = collection.Count() - 1; i < j; i++)
        {
            result += collection[i] + "~";
        }
```

could also be written as:

```
        for (int i = collection.Count() - 1; i > 0; i -= 1)
        {
            result = collection[i] + "~" + result;
        }
```

(and yes, you should o that with a join or a stringbuilder, but I am trying to make a simple example)

There are many other tricks one can use that are not difficult to follow but many of them do not apply across all languages like using mid on the left side of an assignment in old vb to avoid the string reassignment penalty or reading text files in binary mode in .net to get past the buffering penalty when the file is too big for a readtoend.

The only other really generic case I can think of that would apply everywhere would be to apply some Boolean algebra to complex conditionals to try to transform the equation to something that stands a better chance of taking advantage of a short-circuiting conditional or turn a complex set of nested if-then or case statements into an equation entirely.  Neither of these work in all cases, but they can be significant time savers.

Comment: it's a solution, but the compiler will likely spit out warnings as for most common classes length() returns an unsigned type

Comment: But by reversing the index, the iteration itself could become more complex.

Comment: @stijn I was thinking of c# when I wrote it, but perhaps this suggestion also falls in the language specific category for that reason - see edit...  @ToWij certainly, I don't think there are many if any suggestions of this nature that do not run the risk of that.  If your //stuff was some kind of stack manipulation it may not even be possible to reverse the logic correctly, but in many cases it is and is not too confusing if done carefully in most of those cases IMHO.

Comment: you're right; in C++ I'd still prefer the 'normal' loop but with the length() call taken out of the iteration (as in const size_t len = collection.length(); for(size_t i=0;i<len;++i ){} ) for two reasons: I find the 'normal' forward counting loop to be more readable/understandable (but that's probably just because it's more common), and it takes the loop invariant length() call out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. Profile. Do we even have a problem? Where?
2. In 90% cases where it's somehow IO related, apply caching (and maybe get more memory)
3. If it's CPU related, apply caching
4. If performance is still a problem, we have left the realm of simple techniques -- do the math.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the best tools you can find** - good compiler, good profiler, good libraries. Get the algorithms right, or better still - use the right library to do it for you. The trivial loop optimizations are small potatoes, plus you are not as smart as the optimizing compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest one to me is using the stack when possible whenever a common case use pattern fits a range of, say, [0, 64) but has rare cases that have no small upper bound.

Simple C example (before):

```c
void some_hotspot_called_in_big_loops(int n, ...)
{
    // 'n' is, 99% of the time, <= 64.
    int* values = calloc(n, sizeof(int));

    // do stuff with values
    ...
    free(values);
}
```

And after:

```c
void some_hotspot_called_in_big_loops(int n, ...)
{
    // 'n' is, 99% of the time, <= 64.
    int values_mem[64] = {0}
    int* values = (n <= 64) ? values_mem: calloc(n, sizeof(int));

    // do stuff with values
    ...
    if (values != values_mem)
        free(values);
}
```

I've generalized this like so since these kinds of hotspots crop up a lot in profiling:

```c
void some_hotspot_called_in_big_loops(int n, ...)
{
    // 'n' is, 99% of the time, <= 64.
    MemFast values_mem;
    int* values = mf_calloc(&values_mem, n, sizeof(int));

    // do stuff with values
    ...

    mf_free(&values_mem);
}
```

The above uses the stack when the data being allocated is small enough in those 99.9% cases, and uses the heap otherwise.

In C++ I've generalized this with a standard-compliant small sequence (similar to `SmallVector` implementations out there) which revolves around the same concept.

It's not an epic optimization (I've gotten reductions from, say, 3 seconds for an operation to complete down to 1.8 seconds), but it requires such trivial effort to apply. When you can get something down from 3 seconds to 1.8 seconds by just introducing a line of code and changing two, it's a pretty good bang for such a small buck.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are alot of performance changes you can make when accessing data that will have a huge impact on your application. If you write queries or use an ORM to access a databse, then you need to read some performance tuning books for the database backend you use. Chances are you are using known poorly performing techinques. There is no reason to do this except ignorance. This is not premature optimization (I curse the guy who said this because it has been so widely interpeted as never worry about performance), this is good design.

Just a quick sample of performance enhancers for SQL Server:
Use appropriate indexes, avoid cursors - use set-based logic, use sargable where clauses, don't pile views on top of views,  don't return more data than you need or more columns than you need, don't use correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

If this is C++, you should get in the habit of `++i` rather than `i++`.  `++i` will never be worse, it means exactly the same as a stand-alone statement, and in some cases it could be a performance improvement.

It's not worth changing existing code on the off-chance that it will help, but it's a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a little different take on it. Just simply following advice you get here isn't going to make much difference, because there are some mistakes you need to make, which you then need to fix, which you then need to learn from.

The mistake you need to make is to design your data structure in the way everyone does. That is, with redundant data and many layers of abstraction, with properties and notifications that propagate throughout the structure trying to keep it consistent.

Then you [need to do performance tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773) (profiling) and have it show you how, in many ways, what is costing you oodles of cycles is the many layers of abstraction, with properties and notifications that propagate throughout the structure trying to keep it consistent.

You may be able to fix these problems somewhat without major changes to the code.

Then if you are lucky you can learn that less data structure is better, and that it is better to be able to tolerate temporary inconsistency than to try to keep many things tightly in agreement with waves of messages.

How you write loops has really nothing to do with it.